# No exception raised for referenced unassigned array element containing an object

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic-arrays

MRP

```
class B {
    static int v;
    
    public B(int i) {
        System.out.format("Constructor called with value %d\n", i);
        v=i;
    }
}

public class A {
    static B[] c;
    
    A(){
        c=new B[5];
        
        c[1]=new B(1);
    
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            System.out.format("c[%d] is %d\n", i, c[i].v);
        }
        
        c[2]=new B(2);
        
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            System.out.format("c[%d] is %d\n", i, c[i].v);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A();
    }
}

Output is:

Constructor called with value 1
c[0] is 1
c[1] is 1
c[2] is 1
Constructor called with value 2
c[0] is 2
c[1] is 2
c[2] is 2
```

Would expect exception to be raised by reference to unassigned array elements e.g. c[0]. Array values are also incorrectly changed by previous assignment. c[0] is never assigned a value but takes on the values 1 and 2 in the output above.

```
public class A {
    static String[] c;
    
    A(){
        c=new String[5];
        
        c[0]=new String("alpha");
    
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            System.out.format("c[%d] is %s\n", i, c[i]);
        }
        
        c[1]=new String("beta");
        
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            System.out.format("c[%d] is %s\n", i, c[i]);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A();
    }
}


Output for the above is:

c[0] is alpha
c[1] is null
c[2] is null
c[0] is alpha
c[1] is beta
c[2] is null
```

Different behavior is seen for String object in the above example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the question is why doesn't `c[i].v` result in a `NullPointerException` when `c[i]` is `null`.

Lets start with something slightly simpler:

```
B b = null;
System.out.println(b.v);
```

This will not throw a `NullPointerException`.

Why?

Since the `v` field of `B` is `static`, we do not need to dereference the value of `b` to fetch the value of `v`.  The value of `v` is not associated with any specific instance of `B`.

So, in fact, `b.v` and `B.v` are equivalent.

---

In the more general case, consider that `<expr>` is some expression whose static type is `B`.  Then:

```
  V v = <expr>.v
```

has the same effect as:

```
  B temp = <expr>;
  V v = B.v;
```

In other words, the expression is evaluated and its value is discarded.  Then the value of the static field is taken.  But since the `temp` is not dereferenced (because it doesn't *need* to be), there will be no NPE in the case that the expression evaluates to zero ... as it does in your example.

---

The difference in your string example is that you are printing the state of a `String` instance rather than the state of a `static` field.  And no NPE occurs in the string concatenation because the `+` operator maps the `null` to `"null"` rather than calling `null.toString()`.

---

The bottom line here is that using an instance reference to access a static field is a bad idea.  Because the syntax doesn't do what you might expect it to do.

Indeed some Java style checkers / static analyzers will flag that as bad style or a possible bug.

Comment: OK, thx I get it. So the fact that the static field is not associated with an instance means that all instances of B that are referenced by the array values c[0], c[1] and c[2] resolve to the static field.

Comment: That is correct.  (This is one of those cases, where I think they got Java a bit wrong.  IMO `b.v` should be a compilation error if `v` is a `static` field and `b` is not the class that declares `v`.  It would avoid problems like yours ...)